# How to populate components on a new page when clicking on component in current page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a front-end project in React and in it, I want to be able to click on a thumbnail image component on a Home page that will redirect me to another page that renders components depending on the information for the thumbnail component that I clicked on.

For reference, this is a project that allows users to search for recipes from an external API. The thumbnail component they'll be clicking on will be an image and title of a recipe. When they click on that component they will get redirected to a meal page that has components for recipe name, image, servings, ingredients, directions, etc. and those components will render using information from the thumbnail from the Home page.

To summarize, here's what I want to do: When I click on a recipe in the Home page, I want to be redirected to a page that shows information for the recipe I clicked on.

So my main question is 'Is this possible?'

Thanks and feel free to let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It is very possible. It sounds like a normal webpage, and I think most React tutorials on youtube will help you achieve this.

Comment: For me that sounds like you get all the data from your API in a huge request for your thumbnail list. It would probably be better to get the "meal details" when you actually need them (before you load your component).
If that's not possible for you, we talking about data storage across components, which is a different question. Maybe clear that up first

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you probably should use a package named 'react-router-dom'.

1. You should setup a react-router. Here is [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for that.

```js
<Route path="/recipe/:id">
  <RecipePage />
</Route>
```

2. Your thumbnail should [navigate](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) to Recipe Page with the given ID.
3. You should fetch recipe data from API:

```js
// Recipe page  

import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'


const { id } = useParams()
const recipe = await fetch('api/recipe/' + id)
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)